# Настройка UITableView iPhone

Tags: ipad, xcode, ios, objective-c, iphone

Использую таблицу "Grouped"

1. Парсинг парсить в таблицу длинную строку. Как мне сделать так, что б текс автоматически переносился, а таблица растягивалась.
2. Как сделать 1 таблицу для одной цытаты, а 2я что б была в новой таблице.

[image]

На картинке пример того, чего бы я хотел добиться. Заранее спасибо всем iDevelopers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Напишу как бы сделал я, но код напишите сами. Предпологаю что с парсингом вы уже сами справились у вас есть какая-то структура, где хранятся даты, номера и строки (все в целом буду называть сообщением для простоты). Делаете таблицу со свойством style=UITableViewStyleGrouped , в таком случае отдельные секции и будут представлены как таблицы. Количество секций (оно возвращается из numberOfSectionsInTableView: UITableDataSource) равно количеству  сообщений. Далее в каждой секции две ячейки (возвращается из соотв. метода датасорса), верхняя - обычная ячейка номер и дата это textLabel и detailTextLabel ячейки, это обычные UILabel и их внешний вид настраивается, единственное что я не помню точно какой именно из дефолтных стилей ячейки ведет себя так как на картинке, он их там кажется всего 4.

Теперь самое интересное, чтобы задать переменную высоту ячеек надо воспользоваться методом `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` , как не сложно догадаться, indexPath.section -это номер сообщения, а indexPath.row - это либо 0 для номера и даты, тогда можно вернуть константу, либо 1 для длинной строки. Для длинной строки можно использовать метод NSString `- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font forWidth:(CGFloat)width lineBreakMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode`, который даст необходимый размер, на котором она поместится, ну а дальше взять его высоту, добавить немного на отступы и вперед.

Ну а когда будете отрисовывать саму ячейку, нужно будет либо создать новую надпись такого размера, задать ей numberOfLines=0 и добавить на ячейку, либо проделать то же с textLabel ячейки. Узкие места - в первом случае надо помнить про переиспользование ячеек и помещать надпись только один раз при создании ячейки, а во втором не уверен как поведет себя авторасстановка ячейки, возможно надо будет сделать своего наследника и переписать у него layoutSubviews

Comment: спасибо, сечйас буду пробовать!